# Can't start memory profiling using dotMemory

Tags: asp.net, iis, jetbrains-ide, w3wp, dotmemory

I'm attempting to use [JetBrains dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) to profile a ASP.NET MVC web app running on IIS10. When I attach to process *w3wp.exe* and click *Run* get the following error:

> Can't start profiling. Details:
>
> Profiler is unable to attach to the process: Please ensure the process
>   is not run under another profiler, performance monitoring tool,
>   mocking tool, or try to reboot the computer.

I do not have any other profilers or tools that would be running that process.  Also, tried a reboot.  However, nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe dotMemory profiler did not unload it's registration for a process.

Go to dotMemory installation folder (%localappdata%\JetBrains\Installations\dotMemory) and enter the command:
CleanUpProfiler.x64.exe /r /t /i
and restart IIS.

Comment: Thanks! That worked (along with running dotMemory as administrator.)

Comment: Resolved my issue in dotTrace as well. Thank you @Ed.ward!

Comment: Helped me with dotTrace. Thank you @Ed.ward!